# 2D bitmap neighbour grouping

Tags: algorithm, 2d, cluster-analysis, grouping, pixel

Let's say I have a 2D array of 1bit pixels, for example an image bitmap. I would like to find groups/clusters of 2x2 or larger. The groups can take any free form shape larger than that.

Any recommended algorithms for this? For the group boundaries I thinking about 'marching squares' but how about counting the area of each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: use simple logic to find a "seed" of 4 set bits, then use [flood-fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to discover the whole region and calculate its <strike>volume</strike> area.